# Set Increment ID to Dynamically Created Element (DIV) and Assign onclick Event Each DIV

Tags: javascript

I am creating Dynamically DIV and set ID based on AJAX Success Request :

```
$.ajax({

                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        data: '{ goodsName: ' + JSON.stringify(data.goodsName) + '}',

                        url: "calendarView.aspx/getSparepartsFilter",
                        success: function (data, status, xhr) {

                            var divResult = $('#divResult');
                            divResult.empty();
                            $.each(data.d, function (i, v) {

                                   
                                    divResult.append('<div class="col-lg-12 addPart" id="divAddPart"  style="display:block; margin-bottom:3px; cursor:pointer; padding:5px 10px; color:#333; font-size:.8rem; text-decoration:none; border:1px solid #ccc; background:#fafafa ">' + v.goodsName + ' <i class="fa fa-rw fa-circle" style="color:black; margin-left:15px; margin-right:15px; font-size:.4rem;"></i> ' + v.goodsCode + ' <i class="fa fa-rw fa-circle" style="color:black; margin-left:15px; margin-right:15px; font-size:.4rem;"></i> Qty: ' + v.nowStock + ' Available <i class="fa fa-rw fa-circle" style="color:black; margin-left:15px; margin-right:15px; font-size:.4rem;"></i> <input type="number" value="1" width="20px"></input></div>');
                                    count++;

                               
                                }

                            });



                        },
                        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                        }

                    })
```

And I also create one Click Event for those Dynamically created DIV :

```
$(document).on('click', '#divAddPart', function () {//do something})
                    var e = document.getElementById("divAddPart");
                    var c = window.getComputedStyle(e).backgroundColor;
                    console.log(c);
                    if (c === "rgb(250, 250, 250)") {
                        document.getElementById("divAddPart").style.background = "#80c904";
                    } else {
                        document.getElementById("divAddPart").style.background = "#fafafa";
                    }
                })
```

Those event success assigned to the first created DIV only, as I didnt create the increment ID for each DIV.

My question is, how to create the increment ID on every DIV and also assign event.
I think it should create `counter` variable and assign the counter behind `<div id="divAddPart"+counter+""></div>`

But how to assign event on every increment ID ?

I tried to update the onclick event and still error :

```
for (let i = 0; i < counter.length; i++) {
  $(document).on('click', '#divAddPart'+i+'', function () {
                        var e = document.getElementById("divAddPart"+i+"");
                        var c = window.getComputedStyle(e).backgroundColor;
                        console.log(c);
                        if (c === "rgb(250, 250, 250)") {
                            document.getElementById("divAddPart"+i+"").style.background = "#80c904";
                        } else {
                            document.getElementById("divAddPart"+i+"").style.background = "#fafafa";
                        }
                    })
}
```

Comment: id="divAddPart" could be id="divAddPart"+counter and increment that counter at the same time (next line perhaps. I would also put onClick="someFunction(counter)" into that line and make your onClick function a seperate function, e.g. someFunction(counter) to be called taking the counter as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a function instead of adding the onClick to the div dynamically:

```
function someFunction(counter) {
var e = document.getElementById("divAddPart"+counter);
var c = window.getComputedStyle(e).backgroundColor;
console.log(c);
if (c === "rgb(250, 250, 250)") {
    document.getElementById("divAddPart"+counter).style.background = "#80c904";
} else {
    document.getElementById("divAddPart"+counter).style.background = "#fafafa";
}}
```

And make your div append line call that function

```
                                   divResult.append('<div class="col-lg-12 addPart" id="divAddPart"+counter onClick="someFunction(counter)"  style="display:block; margin-bottom:3px; cursor:pointer; padding:5px 10px; color:#333; font-size:.8rem; text-decoration:none; border:1px solid #ccc; background:#fafafa ">' + v.goodsName + ' <i class="fa fa-rw fa-circle" style="color:black; margin-left:15px; margin-right:15px; font-size:.4rem;"></i> ' + v.goodsCode + ' <i class="fa fa-rw fa-circle" style="color:black; margin-left:15px; margin-right:15px; font-size:.4rem;"></i> Qty: ' + v.nowStock + ' Available <i class="fa fa-rw fa-circle" style="color:black; margin-left:15px; margin-right:15px; font-size:.4rem;"></i> <input type="number" value="1" width="20px"></input></div>');
```